# react-three-fiber OrbitControls camera settings don't take effect

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I'm trying to render a huge model using `react-three-fiber` and `drei`'s `OrbitControls`. The model is so huge that gets bigger that the `far` camera plane and gets clipped. But however I set the camera's `far` plane, the `OrbitsControls` ignores it and uses the default value. How can I fix this?

```js
<Canvas>
  <ambientLight />
  <pointLight position={[0, 0, 10]} />

  <OrbitControls
    ref={controlsRef}
    camera={theCamera.current} // tried with/without this line (using this line just creates an empty canvas)
    makeDefault // tried with/without this line
  />

  <PerspectiveCamera
    projectionMatrix={[75, 2, 1, 10000]}
    ref={theCamera}
    far={100000} // even tried to set it like this
    makeDefault // tried with/without this line
  />

  {...TheHugeModel...}

</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To properly modify the (default) camera, try passing the `camera` prop in the `Canvas`:

```
<Canvas camera={{
    near: 0.01,
    far: 10000,
}}>
  <ambientLight />
  <pointLight position={[0, 0, 10]} />

  <OrbitControls makeDefault />

  {...TheHugeModel...}

</Canvas>
```

You can also access the `camera` object with the `useThree` hook - https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/api/hooks#usethree

```
const { camera } = useThree();

useEffect(() => {
    camera.far = 50000;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}, [])
```

Comment: the first piece of code you provided works and solves the problem. but the second one gives me `R3F: Hooks can only be used within the Canvas component!`. can you please provide an example of how to properly use it?

Comment: that code just needs to be in it's own component, that is inside of the <Canvas /> tag